# Bring a frontmatter astro field into the script

Tags: javascript, typescript, astrojs

Good afternoon! At first I tell you that I don't know JavaScript. I understand that it must be a simple question.

My goal is bring a field (Ventana) from above and insert it in the script outside the Astro Fontmatter. This field has content. And this content goes in the part of the script 'SomeThingThatsWork'. Till now the script work if i use quotes and a plain text. So, I understand that my only problem is get the field content inside the script.

```
  ---

  import type { StrapiPost } from '@interfaces/article';

  type Props = StrapiPost;
  const { attributes: {
    title, copete, image, updatedAt, content, slug, fecha, autor, AutorManual, volanta, Ventana
  } } = Astro.props;

  ---
  <script>
  const el = document.querySelector('.current p:nth-child(3)');
  const p = document.createElement('p');
  p.textContent = SomeThingThatsWork;
  p.classList.add('ventana', 'font-helve');

  // Insert before the after element
  el.after(p);
  </script>

  Next come the html code.
```

Thank you for your help and sorry my english.

I tried to copy code but i dont know the semantics so nothing work. The goal is get the content and insert this between the paragraph of an article (this part works!!).

Answer (score 0):

To inject variables from Frontmatter into a script, you can use the following:

```
<script define:vars={{test}}>
```

This will inject the `test` variable into the script.

A full astro page example:

```
---
const test = "Testing!";
---

<div id="out"></div>
<script define:vars={{test}}>
  document.getElementById("out").textContent = test;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Works. I'll edit this answer when I get it working by adding that div after a child paragraph.

For those who are interested: https://docs.astro.build/en/reference/directives-reference/#definevars